# cmake - Troubleshooting LINK_DIRECTORIES

Tags: cmake

My cmake file contains this statement:

```
link_directories("C:/path/to/lib")
```

In the properties of the generated Visual Studio solution I see:

```
/LIBPATH:"C:/path/to/lib"
/LIBPATH:"C:/path/to/lib/Release"
```

I am not sure where that second LIBPATH is coming from.

Within the cmake file I would like to print out the LINK_DIRECTORIES property, how would I do that?  I have tried various things along the lines of...

```
cmake_print_properties(DIRECTORIES xxx PROPERTIES LINK_DIRECTORIES)
```

...but I am not sure what parameters to pass.

**Edit** OK this worked:

```
cmake_print_properties(DIRECTORIES . PROPERTIES LINK_DIRECTORIES)
```

It prints out:

```
 Properties for DIRECTORY .:
   ..LINK_DIRECTORIES = "C:/path/to/lib"
```

So where is that second LIBPATH coming from?  I don't know whether it is generated by cmake somehow, or added later by Visual Studio.

Comment: Does the "Release" subdirectory exist and is it the only subdirectory of /path/to/lib ?

Comment: Yes.  It also happens to be the directory that contains the relevant lib file.  So I suppose there is some machinery in cmake to automatically append Release to the path that I provided but I could not find any mention of that in the documentation and I would like to better understand what is happening.  Many thanks for getting back to me.